trio and rich, live update, abandon_on_cancel, console cursor vanishes
I like to combine async code with a rich tui in a small tool to observe some hardware states.
The tool should run endlessly after it has been started so if somebody wants to control the hardware he does not need to start the tool again and again. However, during development I would like to be able to hard break via strg-c.
The trio part manages scheduling of subprocesses and parsing console output whereas the rich part manages a colourful and easily recognizable console output.
I can run any code asynchronously except the live update of the rich tui.
Therefore, I wrap the live update in a thread and start it via the trio nursery.
In order to make it interuptable via strg-c I specify abandon_on_cancel=True.
async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
    nursery.start_soon(
        lambda: trio.to_thread.run_sync(screen_layout_refresher, abandon_on_cancel=True))
    nursery.start_soon(async_func1, params...)
    nursery.start_soon(async_func2, params...)
    nursery.start_soon(async_func3, params...)

def screen_layout_refresher():
    with Live(the_tui_layout, refresh_per_second=1, screen=True): # the_tui_layout is of type rich.layout.Layout()
        while True:
            # Update some values here

So here is my question:
Everything works fine, except that after pressing strg-c the console cursor disappears, which is sort of nasty if you have to do some console stuff until the next debug cycle.
Does somebody have an explanation for this behaviour?
I can only guess that rich does not reset the cursor colour due to the hard strg-c break?
However, why it becomes black on black background? I do not use a black colour in my console output.

Maybe related: https://github.com/Textualize/rich/issues/2333

Is there maybe a relation to the live display, which turns off the blinking cursor upon entering the with-block but does not turn it on again, after leaving the with-block?
